# Youtube-dl. How to get list of supported sites in python script?

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I have a simple python script which takes a link in clipboard and transfer to youtube-dl:

```
import youtube_dl
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import os

root = tk.Tk()
# keep the window from showing
root.withdraw()
# read the clipboard
clipboard_link = root.clipboard_get()

ydl_opts = { "format": "[height<=480]"}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    get_info = ydl.extract_info(clipboard_link, download=False)

#open url in external player
video_url = get_info["url"]
path_to_player = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\MPC-HC64\mpc-hc64.exe"
subprocess.call([path_to_player, video_url])
```

How can I check a root.clipboard_get() with [list of supported site](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html)
 before assign to clipboard_link?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [youtube-dl FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-can-i-detect-whether-a-given-url-is-supported-by-youtube-dl):

It is not possible to detect whether a URL is supported or not. That's because youtube-dl contains a generic extractor which matches all URLs. You may be tempted to disable, exclude, or remove the generic extractor, but the generic extractor not only allows users to extract videos from lots of websites that embed a video from another service, but may also be used to extract video from a service that it's hosting itself. Therefore, we neither recommend nor support disabling, excluding, or removing the generic extractor.

If you want to find out whether a given URL is supported, simply call youtube-dl with it. If you get no videos back, chances are the URL is either not referring to a video or unsupported. You can find out which by examining the output (if you run youtube-dl on the console) or catching an UnsupportedError exception if you run it from a Python program.